# Pulling and Treating NHL data to handle it in Excel

Tags: python, django, excel

I have a friend who wants to pull NHL data from an API in such a way he could treat it directly in Excel. In fact, he has got a tremendous experience with Excel and wants to make predictions with it.

I would like to create a little web application so that he could make his request easily, directly from an interface.

https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-JSON-API-available-for-getting-NHL-information-rosters-lineups-statistics-etc

**Questions**:

1. If I pull NHL data inside a `.csv` file, will he be able to process information in Excel from that file?
2. Assume I finished this web application, and the API used is no longer supported. I will need to change of API and refactor the entire code so that it will work with the new one. Is there a sort of wrapper I could use to avoid that kind of problem? A type of problem I could encounter is to have to reformat the 'pulling file' so that it could work with my application.

Answer (score 1):

well, you can use openpyxl, is a python library to read/write excel xlsx, xlxm files. Here is a sample:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42

# Rows can also be appended
ws.append([1, 2, 3])

# Python types will automatically be converted
import datetime
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()

# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

for more information read the docs https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/

Here even if you change your api you can still using, just make sure you have the right practices to do that

Answer (score 0):

The first question I think is solved.

The second one the answer is: Yes!
Since the API is modified, you will have to modify your program to account for the changes, and guarantee that its output fit the formats of your csv. In this manner, it would seem that the change in api is transparent for your friend/final user